# How can I hide YouTube progress bar and title

Tags: youtube

I can't deal with translation in the existence of the useless YouTube bar, It shows up every second and takes longer to hide by itself, I do seek forward and backward using arrow keys, is there a way to hide it or move it to the top or decrease its size?

Comment: This seems like something that would be possible with a [userscript](https://openuserjs.org/group/youtube). You use them with a plugin in your browser that runs custom javascript on a specific page or domain.

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this, you need to modify the page in your browser.  There are several ways to do this, but one of the simplest is a JavaScript bookmarklet.

[Here is an intro](http://www.dev-hq.net/posts/1--create-javascript-bookmarklet) to the idea and use of bookmarklets.

[Here is a guide](https://asapguide.com/hide-youtube-bar/) to implementing your specific request using a bookmarklet.

Or, if you already understand bookmarklets, here is code for this one:

```
javascript:(function(){var goaway=".ytp-chrome-top,.ytp-chrome-bottom{display:none;}";if("\v"=="v"){document.createStyleSheet().cssText=goaway}else{var tag=document.createElement("style");tag.type="text/css";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);tag[(typeof document.body.style.WebkitAppearance=="string")?"innerText":"innerHTML"]=goaway}})();
```

Comment: the second method wokred but i have to do that with every video and that's a way annoying 
is there anyway to generalize that on all videos unless I want to disable that 
and does the second video works with firefox